# Difference between vocabulary and get_features() of TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I have

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Train the vectorizer
text="this is a simple example"
singleTFIDF = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2)).fit([text])
singleTFIDF.vocabulary_ # show the word-matrix position pairs

# Analyse the training string - text
single=singleTFIDF.transform([text])
single.toarray()
```

I would like to associate for each value in single the according feature.
What is now the structure of single? How could you map the position of a value in single to the feature?

How can I interpret the indices of vocabulary and get_features()? Are they related? Both have the features with indices according to the documentation. That is confusing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attribute *vocabulary_* outputs a dictionary in which all ngrams are the dictionary keys and the respective values are the column positions of each ngram (feature) in the tfidf matrix. The method *get_feature_names()* outputs a list in which the ngrams appear according to the column position of each feature. You can therefore use either to determine which tfidf column corresponds to which feature. In the example below, the tfidf matrix is easily converted to a pandas data frame using the output of get_feature_names() to name the columns. Also note that all values have been given an equal weight and that the sum of the squares of all weights is equal to one.

```
singleTFIDF.vocabulary_
Out[41]: 
{'this': 5,
 'is': 1,
 'simple': 3,
 'example': 0,
 'this is': 6,
 'is simple': 2,
 'simple example': 4}

singleTFIDF.get_feature_names_out()
Out[42]: ['example', 'is', 'is simple', 'simple', 'simple example', 'this', 'this is']

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(single.toarray(), columns=singleTFIDF.get_feature_names())

df
Out[48]: 
    example        is  is simple    simple  simple example      this   this is
0  0.377964  0.377964   0.377964  0.377964        0.377964  0.377964  0.377964
```

Comment: Ah I see. get_features outputs in the same order as as the order of columns in the tfidf matrix?
Actually I don't understand the output of just single (not with toarray). I has rows like

(0,99) 0.045

So last column is the weight I think, but what is the tuple about?

Thanks!

Comment: The output of single is just the object nformation: <1x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>' with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>. It might be worth running the code again to verify this. I can't reproduce the  (0,99) 0.045 you have commented on.

Comment: Actually, print(single) outputs the same information as  single.toarray() but in a slightly different format - an index tuple (row, column) and the respective weight for each feature: print(single)
  (0, 6)        0.3779644730092272
  (0, 5)        0.3779644730092272
  (0, 4)        0.3779644730092272
  (0, 3)        0.3779644730092272
  (0, 2)        0.3779644730092272
  (0, 1)        0.3779644730092272
  (0, 0)        0.3779644730092272

Comment: Pandas and the tfidf objects have a multitude of methods for processing the data but without a detailed description of what you are aiming for it is not possible to help you. Please consider posting another question.

Comment: What do you mean - what is idf_?

Comment: Probably. Please avoid further questions that are out of the scope of your original question.

Comment: Last need. Do you know how I can multiply the matrix/vector single with another vector like idf_ elementwise?

Comment: single.toarray() * singleTFIDF.idf_

Comment: Yes, but I use then the dot product for cosine similiarity. And this just uses single as input... numpy.dot does not work with single.toarray().

Comment: My previous answer shows you how to calculate the cosine similarity.

Comment: As per [docs] (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) get_feature_names() is deprecated in 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2. Please use get_feature_names_out() instead.